# How does template in c ++ actually work in background?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

**
why the output of code is

```
  x = 1 count = 0

  x = 1 count = 1

 x = 1.1 count = 0
```

**

```
//code for template
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void fun(const T&x)
{
    static int count = 0;
    cout << "x = " << x << " count = " << count << endl;
    ++count;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    fun<int> (1);//for int
    cout << endl;
    fun<int>(1);//for int
    cout << endl; 
    fun<double>(1.1);//for int
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is Compiler creates a new instance of a template function for every data type in c++ in above code  and also how can we assign rvalue to reference variable while calling function fun() ?

Comment: IMHO, the easiest way to understand templates is to think of them as *stencils*, much like artist stencils.   Substitute the data type before evaluation.  There is no "background" for templates.  Thinking of them as stencils can explain why templates can't be in a cpp file.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you have used the stencil to create two functions, one function uses the `int` type, the other function uses the `double` type:

```
void fun(const int &x)
{
    static int count = 0;
    cout << "x = " << x << " count = " << count << endl;
    ++count;
    return;
}

void fun(const double &x)
{
    static int count = 0;
    cout << "x = " << x << " count = " << count << endl;
    ++count;
    return;
}
```

The compiler can recognize the second `fun<int>(1)` as a call to the above integer function, thus not needing to generate a third function.

Passing by reference or `const` reference is the same with `template` functions as it is with normal functions; the `template` only affects the data type, not how parameters are passed.